# Is the Doctor lecturing at River Song's university?

Tags: doctor-who

In *The Pilot* it is revealed the doctor has been lecturing at the university for 50 to perhaps 75 years. **Is this the same university that River Song worked from** ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No.

The Doctor is teaching at the (fictional) **St Luke's University, Bristol**. See the following screencap from about 12:45 through "The Pilot":

[image: Screenshot]

River Song, meanwhile, enrolled at the even more fictional **Luna University**:

> [The Luna University, 5123]
>
> (A professor is interviewing a prospective student.)
> CANDY: So then, tell me. Why do you want to study archaeology?
> RIVER: Well, to be perfectly honest, Professor, I'm looking for a good man.
>
> <sub>-- Series 6 Episode 8, "Let's Kill Hitler"</sub>

Comment: I'm kinda curious how something can be 'even more fictional' than another fictional thing.

Comment: @KyleKanos I was wondering how long it would take before somebody picked up on that. Congratulations, you won today's Pedantry Prize :-)

Comment: excellent, I like prizes, even ones about scrupulous things.